Azure DevOps: Declaring variables whose values are based on certain conditions
In Azure DevOps, am I allowed to declare variables like this?
- name: overrideParameters
  ${{ if contains(lower(parameters.stageDisplayname), 'aa')}}:
    - ${{ if endsWith(lower(parameters.stageDisplayname), 'j') }}: 
        value: '-a "$(Gate.a)" -b "${{ parameters.b }}" -c "${{ parameters.c }}" -d "${{ parameters.d }}" -e "${{ parameters.e }}"'
    - ${{ else }}:
        value: '-a "$(Gate.a)" -b "${{ parameters.b }}" -c "${{ parameters.c }}" -d "${{ parameters.d }}" -e "${{ parameters.e }}" -f 32'
  ${{ else }}:
    - ${{ if endsWith(lower(parameters.stageDisplayname), 'j') }}: 
        value: '-a "$(Gate.a)" -b "${{ parameters.b }}" -c "${{ parameters.c }}" -d "${{ parameters.d }}" -e "${{ parameters.e }}" -f 64 '
    - ${{ else }}:
        value: '-a "$(Gate.a)" -b "${{ parameters.b }}" -c "${{ parameters.c }}" -d "${{ parameters.d }}" -ee "${{ parameters.ee }}" '

Don't mind the parameters, just take a look at the syntax. I modified the actual code so there might be some apostrophes and commas missing, so my advance apologies.
If this do-able, because I am getting an error like this when I do it:


I just had to remove the dashes from the conditions. Something like this:
- name: overrideParameters
  ${{ if contains(lower(parameters.stageDisplayname), 'aa') }}:
    ${{ if endsWith(lower(parameters.stageDisplayname), 'j') }}: 
      value: '-a "$(Gate.a)" -b "${{ parameters.b }}" -c "${{ parameters.c }}" -d "${{ parameters.d }}" -e "${{ parameters.e }}"'
    ${{ else }}:
      value: '-a "$(Gate.a)" -b "${{ parameters.b }}" -c "${{ parameters.c }}" -d "${{ parameters.d }}" -e "${{ parameters.e }}" -f 32'
  ${{ else }}:
    ${{ if endsWith(lower(parameters.stageDisplayname), 'j') }}: 
      value: '-a "$(Gate.a)" -b "${{ parameters.b }}" -c "${{ parameters.c }}" -d "${{ parameters.d }}" -e "${{ parameters.e }}" -f 64'
    ${{ else }}:
      value: '-a "$(Gate.a)" -b "${{ parameters.b }}" -c "${{ parameters.c }}" -d "${{ parameters.d }}" -ee "${{ parameters.ee }}"'

